# java GC heap params for G1

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

I am using below JAVA GC parameters for java 7.

```
-Xmx12g -Xms12g 
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=15 -XX:ConcGCThreads=8 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=16 -XX:G1ConcRefinementThreads=17 -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
```

I would like to know at what % of heap utilization should we see the GC getting triggered.

`-XX:G1ReservePercent=20` : Keeping 20 % reserved.

`-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=15` : Due to this i think when my heap utilize 65% ( total 100 % - 15 = 85 but 20 % reserved so 65 % ) then GC will get triggered.

Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: please check http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/g1gc-1984535.html

Comment: I already checked it and understood. But not sure whether my understanding is correct or not .

Comment: This is quite an old question but I'm wondering a bit why you are setting Xmx == Xms?

Answer (score 0):

Until [JDK-8151176](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8151176) is resolved the IHOP calculation is somewhat idiosyncratic. It is compared against the live set size relative to the total heap, but the live set size can usually not be as large as the total heap because eden and from-space in the young regions will always be empty at the time occupancy is measured.

`G1ReservePercent` is not accounted into IHOP, on the opposite, you need to account for the former when setting the latter.

> total 100 % - 15 = 85

That is backwards. It is about *occupancy*, not free space. It's right there in the name.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand your answers little bit. -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=15 says that when heap occupies 15% then G1 will start marking. That's fine.
 Is there any parameter which tells that at what % of heap utilization GC will trigger?

Comment: requesting your input sir !

Comment: @VJS it will automatically start doing mixed collections once it is done with a concurrent marking cycle.

Answer (score 0):

From parameter definition -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=85 , 
that means mark cycle will start at 85% of total heap(here no other parameter are clubbed with -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent)